# Simon FCC game issues with reseting

Tags: javascript, arrays, reset

Here is my Simon game created for FFC challenge:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/merko30/pen/aYYBjJ)

```
 function reset() {
                pickedColors = [];
                guessingColors = [];
                countNumber = 0;
            }

           start.addEventListener("click", function(){
           reset();
           strict = false;  
           game();  
          }

           strictMode.addEventListener("click", function() {
           strict = true;
           strictLight.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(153, 0, 0)";
           reset();
           game();
          }
```

Problem occures when I switch to strict mode or turn it off, turn it on..

Sometimes it repeat two colors at same time, also sometimes it pushes two same colors to guessingColors array(these are which player clicks).

There is the reset function that empties arrays with colors but problem is still there. It seems like one game didn't stop, and causes duplicating everything(clicks, timeouts .etc)

Comment: Please, amend your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly in the question itself.

Comment: updated post...

Comment: I see, but still there's no MVC in the question. You should reduce your problematic code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem and put it inside the question, inside a code snippet if possible.

Comment: There is the part code which I think could make these problems. You can find game function on the link, it's too long for pasting here..